# Assinatura digital XML com NodeJs

Tags: node.js, assinatura-digital

Bom dia

Estou usando o `xml-crypto` e o `pem` para assinar um XML. Porem depois de pesquisar não encontrei um modo de resolver esta gambiarra:

```
var certificado = cert.cert.toString().replace('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----', '').trim().replace('-----END CERTIFICATE-----', '').trim().replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,"");
```

O código completo da assinatura é esse:

```
pem.readPkcs12('certificado.pfx', { p12Password: "senha" }, (err, cert) => {

var certificado = cert.cert.toString().replace('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----', '').trim().replace('-----END CERTIFICATE-----', '').trim().replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,"");

var sig = new SignedXml()
sig.addReference("//*[local-name(.)='infEvento']", ['http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'])  
sig.canonicalizationAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"  
sig.signingKey = fs.readFileSync('./CertPem.pem')
sig.keyInfoProvider = new myKeyInfo(certificado)
sig.computeSignature(xml, { location: {reference: "//*[local-name(.)='infEvento']", action: 'after'}})
fs.writeFileSync("signed.xml", sig.getSignedXml())});
```

Esta variável `certificado` é adicionada na tag `<X509Certificate>` do xml.
E não encontrei uma forma de obter o valor do certificado sem usar o `replace` na `string` que obtenho.

Comment: Encontrou alguma solução amigo?

Comment: Veja este exemplo em Node.js, acredito que seja o que está procurando. https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/cert_load_from_pfx.asp